# How to check if EFS is mounted on a docker container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have created a task definition and mounted `EFS` but i'm not sure if it works..

So i wanted to verify if my EFS file system is mounted to the running container ?

How can i verify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a file to the folder inside your container:

1. ssh into the underlying ECS EC2 instance with `ssh -i "somekey.pem" ec2-user@ec2-xxxxxxxxx.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
2. Run `docker ps` to get the id of your container.
3. `docker exec -it CONTAINERID /bin/bash` to move inside the container. Inside the container create or copy a file to the EFS-folder.

Now go to the EFS console and verify that the **Metered size** is greater than 0 meaning your file is in EFS.

---

[image]

Comment: yeah i thought of this however the `EFS` console is glitched it does not immediately update the metered size it takes about an hour or so... regardless i waited a bit and did verify by this method itself

Answer (score 1):

You can run a command `df -h` which will list your mounted volumes on linux machines.